# how do i read two bytes in correct order from serial port using win32 api?

Tags: winapi, serial-port, readfile

I am using using win32 api, visual studio 2008. i am able to read bytes from serial port but not the way i intend it to be, I am passing in data from arduino in x,y format. But my code below sometimes read y first then x. How can i read data in the correct order, i mean in x,y order. in case anyone is interested coordinates will be passed to another function and mouse cursor will be move accordingly. Here is my code:

```
int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )

{   
    HANDLE hComm;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    POINT mouseCoords;  /*structur to hold mouse coordinates*/
    DCB dcb = {0};      /*Device Control Block, used to configure serial port settings
                          here we initialize dcb structure to zero. Good practice!*/
    COMMTIMEOUTS ct;

    int loop = 1;
    int counter = 10;

    /*get handle to serial port*/
    hComm = CreateFile(g_pcCommPort, 
                       GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                       0,                           /* must be opened with exclusive-access */
                       NULL,                        /* default security attributes*/
                       OPEN_EXISTING,               /*  must use OPEN_EXISTING for serial ports*/
                       0,                           /*non overlapped I/O, blocking*/
                       NULL );                      /*hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices*/

    /*Make sure that serial port is successfuly opened*/
    if ( hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
            errMsg(TEXT("Cannot access serial port!"));
        return 0;   
    }

    ASSERT("Serial port access successful!");

    /*get serial port status i.e default settings and make
      sure we can access them*/
    if ( !(GetCommState(hComm, &dcb))) {
        errMsg(TEXT("Cannot access current DCB settings!"));
        return 0;
    }

    ASSERT("DCB settings access successful!");

    /*print dcb settings so that we can get an idea of default settings*/
    printCommSettings(dcb);


    /*Since we were successful in accessing the com port
      we can go ahead and set it manually to our desired
      settings*/
    if ( !(setupSerialPort(&dcb))) {
        errMsg(TEXT("Cannot setup serial port!"));
        return 0;
    }

    ASSERT("DCB config successful!");


    /*lets print configuration after setting up the
      serial port just to make sure everything is ok*/
    printCommSettings(dcb);

    ct.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    ct.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    ct.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    ct.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    ct.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if(SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &ct) == 0) {
         errMsg(TEXT("Cannot setup comm timout!"));
    }

while (loop) 
{
  if ( !(ReadFile(hComm,g_buffer,5,&bytesRead,NULL)) ) {    loop = 0; }
    printf("Message Read: %s==%d\r", g_buffer, bytesRead);

} /*while loop*/


    if ( !(CloseHandle(hComm))) {
        errMsg(TEXT("Serial port handle error!"));
    }

    NEWLINE;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
these are serial port settings: 
"9600,N,8,1"

I am passing in 10,12 and this is what i am getting:
OUTPUT:
Message Read: ,12
Message Read: 10,12
Message Read: 12
Message Read: 0,12
Message Read: 2
Message Read: ,12
Message Read: 10,12
Message Read: 12
Message Read: 0,12
Message Read: 2
Message Read: ,12
Message Read: 10,12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you figured out that you're not passing two bytes across the serial port, but in fact you're sending ASCII. And based on your sample output, I don't see the Y coming in before the X (that would show up as `12,10` instead of `10,12`.

What's actually happening is that the reads are not always completing when you expect them to. You get part of the message in one read and the next part in the next read.

What you need to do is synchronize the transmission with some character(s) not found in your message text. For example, if you sent `(10,12)` then you would know that the `(` was the start of your numbers and `)` was the end. That way you could read enough characters in your buffer until you had a `(` followed by a `)` then parse the characters between them, and discard the part of the buffer ending in the `)` character.

Comment: when i have data like (1024, 720) synchronization does not work.

Comment: @rashid: please explain why synchronization wouldn't work with data like `(1024, 720)`.

Comment: it seems to be working. Last night it wasn't behaving very well, but this morning i tried it, and its fine. I must have missed something in my code. Thanks a trillion!!!